# What is the best way to index property DDS EPiServer

Tags: episerver, episerver-6-r2

What is the best way to add indexes on existing objects mapped to DDS? Several hundred thousand objects already stored in the database.

Is it as easy as just adding [EPiServerDataIndex] atttribute to my existing classes, recompile and redeploy the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems your options are to either:

1) Add [EPiServerDataIndex] attributes or...

2) Add indexes through store parameters when creating your store:

`var params = new StoreDefinitionParameters();
storeParams.IndexNames.Add("SomeModelPropertyName");
var store = DynamicDataStore.CreateStore<YourType>("StoreName", params);`

More info [here](http://world.episerver.com/blogs/Paul-Smith/Dates1/2009/11/Changes-in-Dynamic-Data-Store/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ted. So, just annotate the properties of the objects with [EPiServerDataIndex] and indexes will be added. Question is how this will affect objects already stored in DDS.

Comment: The index should apply to items already stored, but I'm not 100 % sure about the DDS internals.